# Importing 3d party JS with Angular2 CLI

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli, parsley.js

Please help me understand once and for all what am I missing.

In angular-cli.json file I put the libraries in **scripts** section, for example:

"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

Is there anything **else** I need to do? Because I have libraries working perfectly fine this way, like bootstrap, but others do not.
For example, even though I put in **scripts** section

"../node_modules/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js",

I keep getting error

***jQuery(...).parsley is not a function(…)*** on usage.

Also, after googling I saw people referencing to angular-cli-build.json file, but I don't have such a file. Do I need it to solve the problem? How do I get it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you included jQuery **before** parsley?

Answer (score 0):

When installing 3rd party libraries, all I have ever needed to do in angular-cli is to npm-install them with --save so that the package.json is updated. If they require additional CSS then I add this under the styles section in angular-cli.json.

Make sure you are using the latest version of angular-cli (there is no angular-cli-build.json in the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these options,

- Try adding these to your root module class `import 'bootstrap'; import 'jquery';`
- You can also use this kind of approach(by writing a custom typings) to resolve this. Include this in your generated typings.d.ts file.

  `interface JQuery {
      parsley(options: any): JQuery;
  }`